# Set Key Value Separator in MapReduce SequenceFileOutputFormat Output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, output

My Mapreduce([CDH 4.3.0](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/api/index.html)) job output is generated in `SequenceFileOutputFormat` using [MulipleOutputs](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) 
as tab separated (Text,LongWritable). I want it to be comma separated (etc).

I have tried using `config_mr.set("mapreduce.output.key.field.separator",",");` but that doesn't help.

Is there anything like `mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator` for `SequenceFileOutputFormat`?

Or do I have to implement RecordWriter ?

<sub>**Note:** If possible please point me to a list with all the properties defined.</sub>

Comment: SequenceFileOutputFormat does not output a text. It outputs some sequence files with special format to store the <key, value> pairs. So there is not separator in it. So I think you mean the separator in your key(the type is Text). But the key is output by your codes. So why can you not control the separator?

Comment: @zsxwing My `key` is of form `a|b|c|d` and `value` is `LongWritable`.Earlier I was including my `value` value in my `key` itself and keeping the actual `value` as `NullWritable`.This is then `sqooped` with
`|` as separator . But I want to ideally use `LongWritable` for value because it is a number. And my output currently is like `a|b|c|d 123`. I cant use `space` as separator for `key` cause it might contain spaces within the data

Comment: Actually, the key in a sequence file can be any Writable. There is no separator concept in a sequence file. Can you use `ArrayWritable` as your key? For example, `ArrayWritable key = new ArrayWritable(Text.class); key.set(new Text[] { new Text("a"), new Text("b"), new Text("c") });`